# Como funciona o pattern Object Linked to Other Objects?

Tags: javascript, design-pattern

O que é o pattern OLOO? Como ele funciona? Qual a sua diferença para o Prototype Pattern? Qual a vantagem de utilização de cada um?

Answer (score 1):

O padrão OLOO cria cadeia `prototype` sem a necessidade do intermédio de outras semânticas (ex. `prototype`, `new`, `function`) para criar e vincular os objetos, tornando-o mais simples que o padrão Prototype.

O OLOO difere do Prototype essencialmente na sintaxe (forma de construção dos objetos e vinculação entre eles):

Veja 2 exemplos em cada padrão na construção do `prototype`:

**Prototype pattern:**

```
function Abc() {}
Abc.prototype.y = 1;
```

**OLOO pattern:**

```
var AbcObj = { y: 1 };
```

Veja que no OLOO a sintaxe é mais simples e direta, sem intermediação da semântica `prototype` e `function`.

---

Agora exemplos de como cada padrão vincula um objeto ao outro:

**Prototype pattern:**

```
function Abc() {}

function Tst() {}
Tst.prototype = Object.create(Abc.prototype);
```

ou

```
function Abc() {}

var Tst = new Abc();
```

**OLOO pattern:**

```
var AbcObj = {};

var TstObj = Object.create(AbcObj);
```

Note que no OLOO basta criar uma variável (`var TstObj`) e vincular diretamente ao outro objeto (`AbcObj`) usando `Object.create()`, sem a necessidade de outras semânticas, como `prototype`, `new` e `function`.

---

**Conclusão:**

Não se pode definir a "*vantagem de cada um*", pois os dois padrões produzem o mesmo resultado, no entanto, o padrão OLOO se mostra bem mais simples do que o padrão Prototype por ter uma sintaxe "mais enxuta", criando e vinculando objetos de forma direta e economizando semântica. Neste conceito, se torna mais vantajoso o uso do padrão OLOO do que o padrão Prototype.

*O material [**nesta página**](https://gist.github.com/getify/5572383) fornece algumas informações sobre o padrão OLOO.*